# analytics and nginx proxy cache

Tags: nginx

I want to use nginx caching for my website, and I came up with this configuration:

```
proxy_cache_key         $scheme://$host$uri$is_args$query_string;
proxy_cache_valid       200 5s;
proxy_cache_valid       404 30s;
proxy_cache_revalidate on;

proxy_cache_background_update   on;
proxy_cache_use_stale updating;
```

now i have couple of questions:

does this mean that every 5 seconds a subrequest by nginx will update the expired data? (im assuming not because its keep giving me `STALE` in cache status when i open a page)

with this configuration im trying to make nginx to update the data every 5 seconds and the users only see the cached data. but i think the stale part means that the data is from previous cache.

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: @RomeoNinov but I think they are related to the same thing which is nginx proxy caching

Comment: Yes, but the rule on SE is one question, one or more answers. If you want you can create several questions for different elements/details.

Comment: @RomeoNinov all right then, i edited the question